# XCode static analyser reports a memory leak when an instance variable is allocated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management

Using XCode 4.2, I am using the static analyser on code similar to the following:

```
@interface ArrayDimensions: NSObject
{
   ArrayIndex *dims;
}
-(id) init: (int *)dims_;
@end

@implementation ArrayDimensions

-(id) init: (int *)dims_
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
      dims = [[ArrayIndex alloc] make:dims_];
   return self;
}
@end
```

The static analyser is reporting that the "method returns with a +1 retain count" and that the "Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced in this execution path".  This is a common type of warning throughout my code and, in each case, it would appear that the analyser fails to recognise that I am setting the value of an instance variable.

My question is whether I am indeed leaking memory or if the analyser is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The analyzer expects that methods return an autoreleased object, unless they are an `alloc`/`init` pair or have `copy` in the name, as per Objective-C method-naming guidelines. Try changing the name of your initialization method from `make:` to `initWithDimensions:` and see if that gets rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release `ArrayIndex` in the `dealloc` method. Also calling a method after `alloc` that does not begin with `init` is discouraged, a bad practice, and possibly confusing the static analyzer.

Here is what you need to add to your `ArrayDimensions` implementation to prevent the actual leak.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [dims release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I meant to mention that I was releasing the member in the dealloc method.  In the cases where I am seeing this problem the analyser doesn't seem to care.  Why is this a "bad practise"?

Comment: Whenever you allocate an object in Objective-C it is immediately followed by some variant of `init`. If you were to give the `ArrayIndex` header file to another Objective-C programmer without instructions I could guarantee you they will instantiate the object incorrectly. Like mipadi said, if `make` is your initializer, rename it to something like `initWithDimensions`. This will likely stop the static analyzer from complaining.